# Why is this Isometry an rotation?

Tags: vectors, rotations, isometry

i need a little help. Did someone have an idea how to prove this?

Thanks in advance.

Be $\Phi$ an direct isometry of the euclidean Space $\mathbb{R}^3$ with

$\Phi (\left(\begin{eqnarray} 2\\0 \\1 \end{eqnarray}\right))$=$\left(\begin{eqnarray} 2\\1 \\0 \end{eqnarray}\right)$ and $\Phi (\left(\begin{eqnarray} 1\\1 \\0 \end{eqnarray}\right)) $=$ \frac{1}{3} \left(\begin{eqnarray} 1\\4 \\1 \end{eqnarray}\right)$

Why is $\Phi$ a rotation?